# SSMS' "Edit Top 200 Rows" will allow edit to 1-row table, but not 2+ row table

Tags: sql-server

The error comes back "no rows was updated...The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows, despite the fact that the table in question has no keys or indexes.

Comment: You need a unique key for the table to be updatable when there is more than one row.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers

Comment: Good stuff guys - unfortunately strongly hobbles the use of this visual "editor" BTW the hyperlink for  "32 other bugs and suggestions " leads into the ether, available anywhere else?